# Cannot find players in Halo 1 (Master Chief Collection)

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I go into multiplayer mode and select any game type. And regardless what game type I select, it says Players Found... (after a little while) but then it does not find any game for me to play.  And it stays that way - there are no error messages.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Are you talking about the HD remake for XBOX 360, or the Master Chief Collection for Xbox One?

Comment: @Ktash Don't forget the very original Halo: CE. It used GameSpy for multiplpayer, which has since been taken down.

Comment: @Ktash The Master Chief Collection for Xbox One.  I'll update the question.

Comment: @AngryHacker, there has been some dispute in the MCC Servers, and as such this could be one of the causes

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.  Per support pages for XBOX, I disabled UPnP, rebooted the router and the cable modem.  Turn off XBOX.  Then turned UPnP back on, rebooted again and restarted XBOX.  That seemed to do the trick.